# Is there a way to obtain information about the instrument to which a Logic Pro X Script is attached?

Tags: javascript, logic-pro-x

Is it possible for a Logic Pro X midi script to query information about the instrument to which it is attached? For example, find out if it is transposed or has a particular midi range filter?

Comment: Not a downvoter but this question seems too be a simple yes/no question.  My guess is that you need to improve the question a bit (research / examples / etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [Scripter API documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/logicpro/scripter-api-overview-lgce3905a48c/10.7/mac/11.0), the answer is no.

The Scripter API provides methods for processing MIDI that are instrument-agnostic.